# Get peak memory as integer on Linux and Mac with the same command

Tags: linux, macos, shell, time

is there a way to get peak memory of a process on Mac and Linux with the same shell command?
Right now I have such logic working on Linix:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%M" myProc 2>$1 | tee memory | tail -n 1 "$log" | int($1)
```

where time -f "%M" changes the output of time to only show peak memory and the rest is getting the value as an integer.

Now I need to do the same for Mac but it does not understand -f, I have tried to use

```
TIMEFMT='%M'
time myProc 2>$1 | tee memory
```

but it stopped working on Linux and had bunch of extra ouput on Mac.

Is there a way to do it better without installing additional dependencies?

Thanks.

Comment: @shellter Did you run your test cast on Mac and did time understand "-f "%M""?

Comment: Ah, .... sorry, I missed that transition to Mac world. I believe there is a gnu package of utilities you can install and likely `date` is included. I see it mentioned regularly in here in comments on other questions. And I would recommend, as this seems to be mostly a Mac question, that you delete here and re-post to [apple.se]. (Deleting my unhelpful comment above, Sorry about that). Good luck!